# starting a new activity causing app crash

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity

Please help me sorting out where I am wrong. Because when I start a new activity using a button click the app crashes.
I am unable to figure out. I used another Acitvity from the same application and it launched successfully. But this nelwy created activity isn't starting in any ways.

My codes are:

```
    [secondscreen.java]
    
    package org......android.activities;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import org......android.R;
    
    public class secondscreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondscreen);
         
            TextView myAwesomeTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myAwesomeTextView);
            myAwesomeTextView.setText("brown fox");
    
    
        }
    }
```

```
    [activity_secondscreen.xml]


    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".activities.secondscreen">
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myAwesomeTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="secondscreen activity"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

```
[starting activity code in a first activity]

buttonTraining = findViewById(R.id.buttonTraining);
        buttonTraining.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"going to second activity...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),secondscreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

```
[partial stacktrace]
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Comment: Please also share the full stacktrace/ logs from logcat for us to understand where the problem is.

Comment: "the app crashes" -- [use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html). If you do not understand what the stack trace means, edit your question and provide the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Worked. After Changed
From

```
    <activity
                android:name=".activities.secondscreen"
                android:exported="false"/>
```

to

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.secondscreen"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```